# Best way to mark up open and closed days for accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

I need to show what days of the week shops are open or closed. What is the best way to do this for accessibility (screen readers etc)?

If possible I would prefere not to use a table as it will make it difficult to achieve the layout that I want for 'normal' users.

```
<h2>First shop</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    Monday open
  </li>
  <li>
    Tuesday closed
  </li>
  <li>
    Wednesday closed
  </li>
  <li>
    Thursday open
  </li>
  <li>
    Friday open
  </li>
  <li>
    Saturday closed
  </li>
  <li>
    Sunay closed
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>Second shop</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    Monday closed
  </li>
  <li>
    Tuesday open
  </li>
  <li>
    Wednesday closed
  </li>
  <li>
    Thursday open
  </li>
  <li>
    Friday open
  </li>
  <li>
    Saturday closed
  </li>
  <li>
    Sunay closed
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use definition lists. They're the HTML equivalent of an associative array. Shortened version:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Monday</dt><dd>open</dd>
    <dt>Tuesday</dt><dd>closed</dd>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</dl>
```

Comment: I think you mean a definition list? Im not sure if your example is how they are supposed to be used. Do you have a source? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

Comment: A definition list is a good way to pair matching bits of information. It can get a bit fiddly with more complex content but for a simple list like this it's perfect.

Comment: It appears youre right. More info here: https://css-tricks.com/utilizing-the-underused-but-semantically-awesome-definition-list/